# Date and time for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How would I go about making an function that does date and time like how apple does in it's apps?(example. Messaging app and note app) What it would do would be after today ends it would say yesterday, and once that exemption fails then it would say the day, up too a week back. Then it would say the day. Would I have to make like a switch statement that checks every time? Because that seems clunky especially if I just want it in the detail section of a table view cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this function to test if the given date is today or not

```
- (BOOL)isSameDay:(NSDate*)date1 date2:(NSDate*)date2 {
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* comp1 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1];
    NSDateComponents* comp2 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date2];

    return [comp1 day]   == [comp2 day] &&
    [comp1 month] == [comp2 month] &&
    [comp1 year]  == [comp2 year];
}
```